# qt run shell commands via qprocess

Tags: c++, linux, bash, qt, shell

I am developing a small QT application to interact with the terminal, to send commands to the terminal and to read back information printed out.

Example: get output of all processes using `ps -aux`

**PROBLEM**

I am able to write information out to the terminal but I dont think it is in the system scope, actual example:

**Command passed to shell interpreter** : `"echo "pre"; ps -aux; echo "post"`

*edit from comment:*

I need to send specific complete commands, I am not looking for shortened or alternative commands, I require a method of sending a command like this : `ps -aux | grep chrome | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2` and reading its output. This example is getting all pid's of all running chrome processes

**Interpreters attempted** :

- `sh`
- `/bin/bash`

**Code:**

```
QProcess *proc_ovpn = new QProcess(this);
proc_ovpn->waitForFinished();
proc_ovpn->start("sh",QStringList() << "-c" << "echo \"pre\";ps -aux; echo \"post\"");
proc_ovpn->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
QString str(proc_ovpn->readAllStandardOutput());
return str;                             <<< ======= //breakpoint here
```

**Debug information:**

When breakpoint is reached, debug information as follows:

```
Locals      
    str ""  QString
    this    @0x555555ad7be0 Interface
Inspector       
Expressions     
Return Value        
Tooltip     
    10000000    10000000    int
```

It was suggested to run shell code using this method above from a post on SO, could not find it again.

I am at a loss, I do not understand why running these commands to not interact directly with the system (and its information),

Any advice?

Comment: Do you need a shell for  `ps -aux`? Why not just use `ps` as the command and `-aux` as the argument?

Comment: @KevinKrammer I need to send complete shell commands and read output, as the one described above, another example is `ps -aux | grep chrome | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2`, this will retrieve all the pid's of all chrome processes. I need to send commands like the one I mentioned and retrieve its output.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just call the `ps` command and then read and process its output?

Comment: @KevinKrammer you seem to be persistent on the idea of an alternative for a specific command. I need to send ANY command to the shell and read the response. How will I process this then `ifconfig | grep tun0 > /dev/null;r=$?;echo $r`. It is exactly the same as the previous. Do you understand now?

Comment: "any command" as in the user types those?
Why would the user not just use a terminal then?

Comment: @KevinKrammer please see answer below, for your own understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `waitForFinished()` after `start`, not before

```
proc_ovpn->start("sh",QStringList() << "-c" << "echo \"pre\";ps -aux; echo \"post\"");
proc_ovpn->waitForFinished();
```

Note that `waitForFinished()` blocks until the process (that has been invoked by `start`) has finished ...

Also, you may check if the process is started successfully and/or if `waitForFinished` timed out

```
proc_ovpn->start("sh",QStringList() << "-c" << "echo \"pre\";ps -aux; echo \"post\"");

if(!proc_ovpn->waitForStarted()) //default wait time 30 sec
    qWarning() << " cannot start process ";

int waitTime = 60000 ; //60 sec
if (!proc_ovpn->waitForFinished(waitTime))
         qWarning() << "timeout .. ";
```

Comment: Quickly read up on the waitForFinished(), it makes sense to have it before, why does it need to be after?

Comment: @KGCybeX you welcome ! .. actually it makes sense to 1-start  2-wait to start 3-wait to finish ..